# Parse.com Swift getFirstObjectInBackground

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Can any one give an example of how use getFirstObjectInBackground and get the first Object returned into a PFObject in Swift?

```
    let weatherObject:PFObject = query.getFirstObjectInBackground() as! PFObject
```

Gives a warning Cast from 'BFTask' to unrelated type 'PFObject' always fails is the warning / error I get in xcode.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variety of get returns a `BFTask` from the bolts framework, which is kind of like a JS promise for the iOS sdks.  Your code casts the return from `getFirstObjectInBackground` to a `PFObject`, which it isn't, as if the method synchronously returns the object you're trying to fetch, which it doesn't.

The fix is either to treat the `BFTask` return value like a `BFTask` and assign it a completion block, or -- easier I think -- use the block variety of the get method (e.g. from [the iOS guide](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-query-constraints)):

```
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (object: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error != nil || object == nil {
    println("The getFirstObject request failed.")
  } else {
    // The find succeeded.
    println("Successfully retrieved the object.")
  }
}
```

If your situation really calls for handling the bolts framework directly, a decent doc for it can be found on its [github page](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS).